# Trying to create an array of filenames

Tags: powershell, pdf

I am trying to use the PSWritePDF module to merge pdfs. I have about 64 folders and each of them have about 20+ files that need to be merged. In the end, I would have 64 pdfs, each containing the merged files from each of the 64 folders. I have already written some code but I am struggling to create an array of file names that I can pass to the Merge-PDF function. I know the first part of this code is redundant, just haven't fixed it yet.

```
#https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWritePDF/blob/master/Example/Example03.Merging/Example03.ps1

#This gives me the 64 folder names
$folder_NM = Get-ChildItem -Path \\main_directory\CURRENT |
           Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
           Foreach-Object {$_.Name}


#This iterates through the 64 folders
foreach ($X IN $folder_NM)
{
#this grabs each of the 64 directories
$main_path = join-path -path \\main_directory\CURRENT -ChildPath $X

#This grabs the names of the pdfs in each folder
$file_names = Get-ChildItem $main_path |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
    
   #This is grabbing each file in the folder and giving me the formatted string I need to pass to Merge-PDF. i.e. C:\\User\Current\pdf.1
   foreach($Y in $file_names){
   $idv_files = join-path -path $main_path -ChildPath $Y
   #This is where I am stuck. I am trying to create an array with each filename comma separated. This currently just overwrites itself each time it goes through the loop.
   $arr = $idv_files-join','
   
    #This is needed for mergePDF
    $OutputFile = "$maindirectory\TESTING\$X.pdf"
    #This only puts the most recent file in the output file. Thus the need for an array of file names.
   Merge-PDF -InputFile $arr -OutputFile $OutputFile

   #Debugging
   #Write-Host $arr
   }


}
```

Specifically, this is where I am struggling. I am getting the correct files in $idv_files and if I use those in Merge-PDF then I just get a PDF with the one file that was processed last. I think I just need them comma separated and all put into the same array so that Merge-PDF will merge them all together.

```
foreach($Y in $file_names){
   $idv_files = join-path -path $main_path -ChildPath $Y
   #This is where I am stuck. I am trying to create an array with each filename comma separated. This currently just overwrites itself each time it goes through the loop.
   $arr = $idv_files-join','
```

Anything helps. Very new to powershell!

Comment: Seems like `Merge-PDF -InputFile` takes `[string[]]` as input. If that's the case then, you should __definitely not__ use `$idv_files -join ','` and pass the function a string array with paths instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but, if the function takes `[string[]]` as input as in my comment, this should get you a `MERGED PDF.pdf` on each folder.

I would recommend you to test this with a few folders containing pdf files on your local host before trying with your FS.

```
# Get the Directories
$folder_NM = Get-ChildItem -Path \\main_directory\CURRENT -Directory

#This iterates through the 64 folders
foreach ($dir IN $folder_NM)
{
    # This gets you the array of PDF Files
    $file_names = Get-ChildItem $dir.FullName -Filter *.pdf -File |
                  Sort-Object Name
    
    # Define the output file for Merged PDF
    $OutputFile = Join-Path $dir.FullName -ChildPath 'MERGED PDF.pdf'
    
    # If Merge-PDF takes [string[]] as input, this should work
    Merge-PDF -InputFile $file_names.FullName -OutputFile $OutputFile
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I hadn't full converted everything and this is working so thanks a ton! I Just need to order the $file_names variable alphabetically then I am good to go!

Comment: @user3870118 good to know and happy to help! See my edit, I added `Sort-Object Name` for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that you wanted the merged .pdf file to be the subdirectory name + '.pdf'. Perhaps I misunderstood. This is also UNTESTED, but might do what you want. Using the current Windows PowerShell 5.1 or any PowerShell Core, testing for .PSIsContainer is not necessary. Get-ChildItem supports -File and -Directory switches.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()
$RootDir = '\\main_directory\CURRENT'
# Get the subdirectory list.
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $RootDir |
    # Process each subdirectory.
    ForEach-Item {
        # Create an array of the .pdf files to be merged.
        $file_names = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.pdf').FullName
        #This is needed for mergePDF
        $OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $RootDir -ChildPath $($_.Name + '.pdf')
        Write-Verbose "OutputFile is $OutputFile"
        Merge-PDF -InputFile $file_names -OutputFile $OutputFile
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write a fresh custom module each time, I simply run a generic.ps1 script from batch files. (As written it will need file-sets be ordered 00-99) however there do not need to be 100 and if more than 100 can be run more than once by fast 2nd pass on the output as merged100-00 merged100-## etc. thus upto 9999 files speedily.

so the basic script is PDFmerge##.ps1 (I am sure its not good syntax, but works!)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
$Fin = $args[0]
$Ext = $args[1]
$Out = $args[2]
echo "Merging $Fin##$Ext to $Out"
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt 10; $j++) {
        New-Variable -Name "F$i$j" -Value "$Fin$i$j$Ext"
    }
}
echo Processing
Merge-PDF -OutputFile $Out -InputFile $F00, $F01, $F02, $F03, $F04, $F05, $F06, $F07, $F08, $F09, $F10, $F11, $F12, $F13, $F14, $F15, $F16, $F17, $F18, $F19, $F20, $F21, $F22, $F23, $F24, $F25, $F26, $F27, $F28, $F29, $F30, $F31, $F32, $F33, $F34, $F35, $F36, $F37, $F38, $F39, $F40, $F41, $F42, $F43, $F44, $F45, $F46, $F47, $F48, $F49, $F50, $F51, $F52, $F53, $F54, $F55, $F56, $F57, $F58, $F59, $F60, $F61, $F62, $F63, $F64, $F65, $F66, $F67, $F68, $F69, $F70, $F71, $F72, $F73, $F74, $F75, $F76, $F77, $F78, $F79, $F80, $F81, $F82, $F83, $F84, $F85, $F86, $F87, $F88, $F89, $F90, $F91, $F92, $F93, $F94, $F95, $F96, $F97, $F98, $F99
echo "Done Merging $F00 - $F99"
```

and called similar to merge all "dev:/input path/partBefore"##"partAfter.pdf"

```
powershell -file PDFmerge##.ps1 "input/partBefore" "partAfter.pdf" "output/Parts01.pdf"
```

e.g. for /folder/##.pdf would simply be "/folder/" ".pdf" "/folder/out-01.pdf"
which  itself can be looped list of folders as per other methods.